# WPF: How to create events for custom usercontrols?

Tags: wpf, event-handling, wpf-controls

I have created a `UserControl` that consists of an `ItemsCollection`. Each item in this collection consists of a `ListBox`.

My application is represented by a `Window`, which contains this `UserControl`. I want to be able to manage events related to items inside the `ListBox`. How can I achieve this? (I am not sure if this is relevant or not, but the `UserControl` is in a assembly different from the application.)

Here's the code of the `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="UserControls.CalendarMonthViewControl.CalendarMonthView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignWidth="580" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" 
    xmlns:calendarMonthViewControl="clr-namespace:UserControls.CalendarMonthViewControl" 
    Name="CalendarMonthViewControl">
  <Grid>
    <ItemsControl 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=CalendarMonthViewControl, Path=Days}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <UniformGrid Rows="6" Columns="7" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type calendarMonthViewControl:Day}">
          <Border>
            <Grid>
              <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CalendarDayItems}" />
            </Grid>
          </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Where do you want to handle the ListBox events? In the window, the user control or somewhere else? Someone has to "handle" the event.

Comment: I want to handle the events in the code-behind of the `Window`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@vlad is on the right track.

There's a couple of options here. Both of them involve handling routed events.

To handle a routed event, you use the name of the owning class followed by the name of the event.

The first option is to simply handle the selection changed events (or some other `ListBox` event) on the `Window` class:

```
<Window ...
        ListBox.SelectionChanged="OnChildListboxSelectionChanged">
   ...
</Window>
```

The second option (more typical approach) is to handle the `ListBox` events inside of the UserControl and then aggregate them in some way and fire an event at that level. This event is then handled by the `Window`. This event could be a routed event or a standard .NET event.

```
<UserControl ...
             ListBox.SelectionChanged="OnChildListBoxSelectionChanged">
   ...
</UserControl>
```

Code behind for user control:

```
public event EventHandler<MyArgTypeEventArgs> ListBoxUpdated;

private void OnChildListBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   // aggregate data and info
   MyArgTypeEventArgs handler = ListBoxUpdated;
   if (handler != null)
      handler.Invoke(this, GenerateArgs());
}
```

The `Window` handles this event:

```
<Window ...
        ListBoxUpdated="OnListBoxUpdated">
   ...
</Window>
```

This should give you something to start with.

Comment: Note that you could follow a similar approach using MVVM if you desire. The view would have to notify the view model when the event occurred and then the view model would aggregate and propagate the event.

Comment: MVVM shines best when working with DataTemplates inside of ItemsControls or ListBoxes. It can be very difficult to have logic associated with individual items inside of an ItemsControl without using view models in the control.

Comment: Thanks so much. I've decided to give MVVM a shot (I've never used in my coding before).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used them much myself, but I think [RoutedEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) would solve your problem.  The events bubble up from your `ListBox` to the `Window` (or another element lower in the tree) where you can handle them.

**edit**: quoting from the link: To add a handler for an event using XAML, you declare the event name as an attribute on the element that is an event listener. The value of the attribute is the name of your implemented handler method, which must exist in the partial class of the code-behind file.

since [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx) inherits from `UIElement`, I'm guessing something like this would work (untested atm):

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="UserControls.CalendarMonthViewControl.CalendarMonthView"
    [...]
    ListBox.NameOfEvent="EventHandlerName">
```

Comment: @Boris added details. @JoshG has some nice code for the event handler, too

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're trying to do is the right approach as it's creating unnecessary dependence between your views and means that your UserControl is not properly encapsulated.

In my opinion the nice solution would be to handle events in your UserControl's viewmodel and set up a relation between the viewmodel of your Window as needed, so that the views themselves are independent.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Ok, let's say I call an event inside the `UserControl`. The code-behind of the user control would contain the event handler. How can I reach that method from within the `Window` code-behind that contains that `UserControl`? Or, if I am thinking wrong again, could you please help me understand the way it should be done? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Could be done with a mediator. It all depends on how your pieces are coupled. If you are using MVVM, it's going to depend on how your view models are coupled.

Comment: @Boris, as Josh says you'll need something to glue these views, by the sounds of it you're not using MVVM, I'd give it a read and cut back on code behind, it'll pay back later having a cleaner architecture with the views and your business logic nicely separated!

Comment: thanks for the help. I'll give MVVM a try. (Btw, you were right, I've never used it :)